# Get Identity.Errors in controller with Identity Framework

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

In .net core with Identity, actually I have a service class `UserService` consuming the UserManager class and returning a User Class.

```
public UserService(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

In this class, I am creating an `IdentityUser` and I'm using the `IdentityResult` to get the query status.
If I would have used the `UserManager` directly in my controller, I would do that in case of failure:

```
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    return BadRequest(result.Errors);
}
```

The service class is returning a User, therefore I can't use an `IdentityResult` in my controller and I've lots `result.Errors` to put in the `BadRequest`.

How to catch this errors in the controller (to have it directly in the get request result)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I dealt with like that:

Custom exception with custom property

```
public UserServiceException(IEnumerable<IdentityError> errors)
{
    Errors = errors;
}
```

then throw the custom exception in service class

```
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    throw new UserServiceException(result.Errors);
}
```

And catch it in controller

```
catch(UserServiceException ex)
{
    return BadRequest(ex.Errors);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way we could do this is by creating a new class, like say , a "ServiceResponse" class. This new class would include your User object and also a list of errors. Then, your UserService would return a ServiceResponse instead of just a User.

Here's a rough idea of what the ServiceResponse class might look like:

```
public class ServiceResponse<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Your UserService can now return a ServiceResponse. If something goes wrong , you can add the error messages to the Errors list and switch the Success property to false. Your controller can then check this Success property and return the Errors list if needed.

Here's how you could use it when creating a user:

```
public ServiceResponse<User> CreateUser(string username , string password)
{
    var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<User>();
    var user = new User { UserName = username };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user , password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        serviceResponse.Success = false;
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            serviceResponse.Errors.Add(error.Description);
        }
        return serviceResponse;
    }

    serviceResponse.Data = user;
    return serviceResponse;
}
```

Finally, in your controller, you'd call the CreateUser method, check if Success is false , and if so, return BadRequest:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(string username , string password)
{
    var response = await _userService.CreateUser(username , password);
    if (!response.Success)
    {
        return BadRequest(response.Errors);
    }
    return Ok(response.Data);
}
```

Comment: It was my first idea but I think in term of design that's better to keep the User class (maybe I'm wrong). I having a look on another option which id to throw an exception in the service and catch it in the controller.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: I really suspect you are a not-so-smart robot @ tchrist

Comment: @tchrist, what answer are you talking about? Agree Nail, better improve their algorythm...